# AngularJS height counter directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
On -/+ click add or remove an inch from the height counter and display height in foot/inch format (6'4").

**Current Problems:**
When attempting to edit [Maikel Daloo](http://maikeldaloo.com/post/angularjs-counter-directive) Counter Directive the AngularJS project displays a blank page.

Any help and advice would be helpful,
Thank you.

**Original Source:** http://maikeldaloo.com/post/angularjs-counter-directive
**Plnkr:** http://plnkr.co/edit/8mzg4QHKDHwgfSiy1XqL?p=preview

**Directive:**

```
fittingApp.directive('counter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { value: '=value' },
        template: '<a href="javascript:;" class="counter-minus" ng-click="minus()">-</a><a  href="javascript:;" class="counter-plus" ng-click="plus()">+</a><input type="text" class="counter-field" ng-model="value" ng-change="changed()" ng-readonly="readonly">',
        link: function( scope , element , attributes ) {
            if ( angular.isUndefined(scope.value) ) {
                throw "Missing the value attribute on the counter directive.";
            }
            var min = angular.isUndefined(attributes.min) ? null : parseInt(attributes.min);
            var max = angular.isUndefined(attributes.max) ? null : parseInt(attributes.max);
            var step = angular.isUndefined(attributes.step) ? 1 : parseInt(attributes.step);
            element.addClass('counter-container');
            scope.readonly = angular.isUndefined(attributes.editable) ? true : false;
            var setValue = function( val ) {
                scope.value = parseInt( val );
            };
            setValue( scope.value );
            scope.minus = function() {
                if ( min && (scope.value <= min || scope.value - step <= min) || min === 0 && scope.value < 1 ) {
                    setValue( min );
                    return false;
                }
                setValue( scope.value - step );
            };
            scope.plus = function() {
                if ( max && (scope.value >= max || scope.value + step >= max) ) {
                    setValue( max );
                    return false;
                }
                setValue( scope.value + step );
            };
            scope.changed = function() {
                if ( !scope.value ) setValue( 0 );
                if ( /[0-9]/.test(scope.value) ) {
                    setValue( scope.value );
                }
                else {
                    setValue( scope.min );
                }
                if ( min && (scope.value <= min || scope.value - step <= min) ) {
                    setValue( min );
                    return false;
                }
                if ( max && (scope.value >= max || scope.value + step >= max) ) {
                    setValue( max );
                    return false;
                }
                setValue( scope.value );
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller:**

```
fittingApp.controller('statsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.height = 3;
    $scope.chest = 3;
    $scope.waist = 3;
    $scope.hips = 3;
    $scope.thighs = 3;
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<h4>Height:</h4>
<div counter min="0" value="height"></div>
<h4>Chest:</h4>
<div counter min="0" value="chest"></div>
<h4>Waist:</h4>
<div counter min="0" value="waist"></div>
<h4>Hips:</h4>
<div counter min="0" value="hips"></div>
<h4>Thighs:</h4>
<div counter min="0" value="thighs"></div>
```

**Design:**
[image]
**Development:**
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you run the edited directive?

Comment: Now that I have reverted to Maikel Daloo default Directive the Height, Chest, Waist, Hips and Thighs are displaying again and you are able to click -/+ to add and remove digits but hight doesn't work as foot and inches...

Comment: Create a fiddle of which will help to debug more

Comment: @AnandG http://plnkr.co/edit/8mzg4QHKDHwgfSiy1XqL?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think keep the value of the counter as a full number, then as you're displaying the value in feet/inches, you should use a filter to perform the conversion.

Similar to how you do currency in Angular, where you'd have something like this:
{{total | currency}}.

You could technically have something like the above. https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

UPDATE:

Take a look at this file - I've added a comment in each of the files to tell you what new bits I've added.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YueSevu6YWI1RphoY7h3?p=preview

```
- Bumped the steps to 10, added a minimum of 100
- Added an inches filter (basic one)
- Set the counter fields as hidden
- Placed value outside of the counter elements.
```

Comment: Thank you Maikel, I really appreciate all the extra input and advice. 
I've quickly mocked a Plnkr together, would you be able to review and let me know if I have implemented everything correctly! http://plnkr.co/edit/I1s24nojfkuHAw6FSzEF?p=preview

Comment: Looks good :) it's doing the job. Don't forget to add `user-select: none` on the buttons to not allow selections when you click quickly.